# Play sound from Apple Watch speaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, apple-watch

Is there a way to play sound out of the Apple Watch's speaker? I have been unable to find any documentation online.

Comment: It is not possible, https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254687?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks! Post it as an answer so I can verify

Comment: Wait, that link doesn't work for me

Comment: Works now, something is wrong with their redirect, you have to go manual setup an apple forums account then click the link again.

Comment: requires developer account

Comment: For WatchOS3 there is a new widget. See my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is now possible as of watchOS 2 using `WKAudioFilePlayer` or `WKInterfaceMovie`.

```
NSURL *assetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file" withExtension:@"wav"];
```

`WKAudioFilePlayer` example:

```
WKAudioFileAsset *asset = [WKAudioFileAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
WKAudioFilePlayerItem *playerItem = [WKAudioFilePlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
WKAudioFilePlayer *audioFilePlayer = [WKAudioFilePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[audioFilePlayer play];
```

`WKInterfaceMovie` example:

```
[self presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:assetURL options:nil completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is actually not the answer to the question, because the snippet does not play a sound file through the watch's speaker, but through paired Bluetooth headphones: "A WatchKit extension may initiate the playback of extended audio content through a paired Bluetooth audio headset." https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/ManagingYourData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH12-SW6

Comment: @MichaelDorner that's not true "Audio in your media files is routed to a paired Bluetooth headset if one is available. If no Bluetooth headset is available, audio is routed to the Apple Watch speaker."

Comment: I tested it with watchOS 2.0 and could not see this routing. What have you done? Would be cool, if this is working. :-)

Comment: Please, how to implement streaming radio playback on a Watch App?

Comment: i did this and I did not have any sound from the watch speakers. I'm not sure this works. I'm on watchos 3.

Answer (score 5):

```
import AVFoundation
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "siren", ofType: "wav") {

        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do{
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileUrl)

            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.play()

        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

I've used this to play a custom sound from the apple watch(4.3) speaker and worked just fine.
Don't forget to set the audio file target membership to the watch kit.

Comment: Does this work in watchOS 5 for you? It isn't working for me (doesn't play through the speaker)

Comment: is the speaker available for watch OS simulator?

Answer (score 3):

- presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:options:completion:
  (New in watchOS 2.0)

URL 
The URL of the media file you want to play. The URL must specify a file; streamed media is not supported. The file may contain audio, video, or both.

If you specify a URL for a file on a remote server, this method downloads the file first and displays a progress indicator showing the progress of the operation. Because WatchKit uses App Transport Security (ATS) when downloading files from a web server, the file must be on a secure server, and the URL must use the https scheme. If your server does not support ATS–level security, download the file yourself before playing it.

Use sharedcontainer, watch extensions, for storing the file.

Any audio you play using this method is routed to a paired Bluetooth audio device if one is available. If no Bluetooth audio device is available, audio is routed to to the Apple Watch speaker.

Comment: I am trying to playback a streamed media (radio). I have failed in the attempt and also I have received the error message: App Transport Security (ATS). How I can play a streaming radio?

Answer (score 3):

For WatchOS3 the answer to the original question is WKInterfaceInlineMovie
https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfaceinlinemovie

You can hide the widget so it does not alter your interface design. It plays audio files through the watch's speaker if no bluetooth speaker is connected.

Comment: Any idea why the volume is not using the value from the system? I've put it at the minimum in the Watch settings but its blasting super loud. I haven't found any parameter to change the volume either.

Comment: Do you know hoow to hide the widget?

Comment: Same as hiding any widget: set the widget's hidden property to true/YES or check the hidden property in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3):

## In the InterfaceController.swift file

Works Fine In Simulator & Device Also
Available in latest WatchOS 5

```
import AVFoundation

var player = AVAudioPlayer()
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()


    override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    
    do {
        // Working Reroutes to headset
        //            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
        //                                    mode: .default,
        //                                    policy: .longForm,
        //                                    options: [])
        
        // Plays in watch speaker
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
                                mode: .default,
                                policy: .default,
                                options: [])
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("*** Unable to set up the audio session: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
    }
    if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "piano", withExtension: "mp3") {
        let fileUrl = path
        do{
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileUrl)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("*** Unable to set up the audio player: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
            // Handle the error here.
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Use this code to call the audio session and play the audio inside the play button action or on whichever case you want the audio to play.

```
     audioSession.activate(options: []) { (success, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("*** error occurred: \(error!.localizedDescription) 
                     ***")
                // Handle the error here.
                return
            }
            if(success){
                // Play the audio file.
                self.player.play()
            }
        }
```

If you are still not being able to play audio , it must be because you are getting a nil value in the audio file , the audio file specified would not be in the right bundle you are searching for

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to play sound out of the Apple Watch's speaker, but you can trigger playing a sound file on the iPhone, here is [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254687?tstart=0) about it