# Play sound on Apple Watch from iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

Can't find a clear answer on the internet.
I want to make an iOS App, which can play a sound on the Apple Watch, like you can play a sound on your iPhone from the Apple Watch (by swiping up from the watch face.)

Anyone knows if thats possible?

Cheers!

Matthijs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play sound from Apple Watch speaker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980152/play-sound-from-apple-watch-speaker)

Comment: No duplicate, that post is about making a watch os app play a sound on the speaker, now I want to make an iOS app which can play a sound on the watch.

Comment: As I know, there is no explicit way to do that in vanilla iOS and watchOS (no jailbreaking). Maybe you could try making notification, so a sound will be played.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to play (stream?) sound from iPhone? Why don't you play sound on the Watch, placing playback controls on the iPhone?